# Remove double backslashes c# (for use ESC/POS programming)

Tags: c#

I've seached a long time, and it seems that my problem is world-wide known. But, all the answers that are given, won't work for me. Most of the time, people say 'there is no problem'.

The problem: I'm programming a POS solution, and I'm using a Epson POS printer. To print the buttom to the receipt, I'm storing a string in the database. This is, so users can adjust the text at the bottom of the receipt. But, when I'm pulling the string out of the database, C# adds slashes to the string, so my excape characters won't work. I know, that usualy is not a problem, but in my case it is, because my ECS/POS commands won't work.

I've already tried some scripts, which replaces the double \ with a single \, but they don't work. (eg. String.Replace(@'\\',@'\').

Problem:

I have a sting: "foo \n bar"

Needs to print as:

foo

bar

C# adds slashes: "foo \\n bar"

Now it's printed as:
foo \n bar

Anyone an idea?

Comment: i think you are confusing what the debugger shows you with the real string

Comment: Please show a short but complete demonstrating the problem *without* using the debugger.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the database does _not_ contain the extra backslashes?

Comment: Yes, in my SQL database are no extra slashes

Comment: You need to replace the literal `\n` with a carriage return/line feed before you output the string, e.g. `String.Replace( @"\n", Environment.NewLine )`

Comment: "\n" is just an example, there are al lot of esc codes. Is there no way I can just send the original string, without the extra slashes?

Comment: It _is_ sending the correct string. The database happens to contain strings with funny punctuation marks. .NET doesn't interpret them on the way by, it just sends them out. You seem to be confused, as suggested earlier, by the debugger's display. If _you_ think there are strings with special meanings, you will have to handle them.

Comment: @T.Jansman "\n" is **not** a new line. Does the original string contain a new line character? (`\n` in c# or 0xA)? if not you'll need to find and replace the string "\n" with the char '\n'

Comment: @HABO Okay, maybe i'm confused, but I don't know why.

The thing is, when I'm programmaticly create a printline, it worked:
PrinterStation.Receipt, "\u001b|1C" + "Korting:" +"\n");

But, the exact same string, out of the database, failes:
"\u001b|1CKorting:\n"

Comment: @T.Jansman .NET isn't adding the backslashes, that's only in the debugger display. In other things, you're reading `foo \n bar` from the DB - it's *not* stored as `foo <newline> bar`. However, .NET will not interpret that `\n` as a newline character, because it's not the newline character, it's a literal `\n`. If you want it to be interpreted as a newline character, you need to do `@"foo \n bar".Replace(@"\n", "\n")`.

Comment: Try a simple console program that reads the strings from the database and displays them. You'll find that the display matches the contents of the database, i.e. the program does not interpret the characters in any special way. If the string contains control characters, e.g. CR, LF, TAB, ..., then they will affect the display. Some displays, e.g. browsers and printers, do their own processing. A printer typically looks for ESC sequences that control fonts and the like. A browser interprets HTML tags.

Comment: Okay. But, when the program IS using the orginal string (so without the backslashes), do you have any idea why the printer won't accept the excape codes? Like I said: PrinterStation.Receipt, "\u001b|1C" + "Korting:" +"\n" works like charm, but when I store \u001b|1CKorting:\n in the database, and print it as string, it won't accept the escape characters.

Comment: When you use a string in C# it processes escape sequences: `string foo = "a\nb";` converts the "\n" into a newline in the string. A [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), indicated by a leading at-sign, won't do that: `string bar = @"a\nb";`.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and knowlegde. To fix the poblem, I've created some words, that later can be replaces by ESC codes, so the codes won't be in de database.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a misunderstanding of how C# handles strings. Take the following sample code:

```
string foo = "a\nb";
int fooLength = foo.Length; \\ 3 characters.
int bar = (int)(foo[1]); \\ 10 = linefeed character.
```

versus:

```
string foo = @"a\nb"; \\ NB: @ prefix!
int fooLength = foo.Length; \\ 4 characters.
int bar = (int)(foo[1]); \\ 92 = backslash character.
```

The first example uses a string literal (`"a\nb"`) which is interpreted by the C# compiler to yield three characters. The second example uses a [verbatim string  literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), due the prefix @, that suppresses the interpretation of the string.

Note that the debugger is designed to add to the confusion by displaying strings with escape codes added, e.g. `string foo = "a\nb" + (Char)9;` results in a string that the debugger shows as `"a\nb\t"`. If you use the "text visualizer" in the debugger (by clicking on the magnifying glass when examining the the variable's value) you can see the difference between literal and interpreted characters.

Databases are, as a rule, designed to accept and return string values without interpretation. That way you needn't worry about names like "Delete D'table". Neither the presence of a SQL keyword, nor punctuation used in SQL statements, should present a problem in a data column.

Now the OP's issue should be becoming clearer. The string retrieved from the database does not contain a linefeed, but instead contains the characters '\' and 'n'. .NET has no reason to change those values when the string is read from the database and written to a printer. Unfortunately, the debugger confounds the difference. (Use the text visualizer as described above.)

The solution involves adding code to reproduce the C# compiler's processing of escape sequences. (This should include escaping escape characters!) Alternatively, tokens can be added that are suitable for the application at hand, e.g. occurrences of `«ESC»` could be replaced with an ASCII escape character. This can be employed for longer sequences, for example if a print uses several characters to introduce a font change then write the code to replace `«SetFont»` with the correct sequence. More generally, you can replace a *snippet* with a dynamic value, e.g. `«Now»` could be replaced with the current date/time when the receipt is being printed. (Register number, cashier name, store hours, ... .) This makes the values in the database more human readable than embedded Unicode oddities and more flexible than fixed strings.

Left as an exercise for the reader: extend snippets to support formatting and null value substitution.  `«Now|DD.MM.YY hh:mm»` to specify a format, `«Discount|*|n/a»` to specify a value ("n/a") to be displayed if the field is null.